# Facebook Access Token expired or not

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

How to check if access token expired or not using Facebook PHP SDK ???

Becuase its not documented i guess, and this link is not about SDK, isn't it ? So is they any way to check that using SDK or do I need to use curl ?

[https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/)

Comment: Who vote down this huh ??? Im asking a critical question here because, I searched and couldn't find any kind of suitable answer for this question !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check if access token expired or not using Facebook PHP SDK ?

There’s an API endpoint for that purpose, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/

Comment: Is that new? I've never seen documentation for that before. Very useful.

Comment: Yes, I think it is relatively new – and even I knew there was a docs page for this I had to search for it for a while, because they changed the structure of the documentation recently … again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

To get token expiration and other related token information you can make a GET call to Graph API debugging endpoint as show below.

```
GET /debug_token?
     input_token={input-token}&
     access_token={access-token}
```

`input_token` the access token you want to get information about

`access_token` your app access token or a valid user access token from a developer of the app

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire this api call th know the status of access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token_info?access_token=xxxxxxxxx
```

It will show `expires_in`: `SECONDS_TO_EXPIRE`